# fatal error file not found /Lexical preprocessor error IOS

Tags: ios7, build, xcode5.1

I have a project deployed on the appstore(everything ok),which after 2 months on running source code gives me crazy errors.

what i tried

> Build settings->  set YES to Always search user paths

Not working

Please provide some suggestions.I think i need to chang some thing in build settings.Do anyone know  why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: i have moved the location of the file.I think that might be the problem.What should i change in build settings if that is the case

Answer (score 0):

I was able to  solve it in 2 ways

1.I removed the framework and added it back again
2.In framework search paths i removed everything and added  $(SRCROOT) there.